# Two real numbers which belong to distinct classes in the quotient group $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $x,y$ two real numbers.
What does mean, in "pratical terms", that "$x,y$ belong to distinct classes in the quotient group $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$"? Maybe that their difference $x-y$ isn't an integer multiple of 1? And if so, who can tell me why?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is exactly what is meant. In the mapping $\pi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, two numbers, $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$, will be mapped to the same equivalence class $\iff$ $x-y\in \mathbb{Z}$. In "practical terms" this means we can look at just a single interval of the real line to find one of every coset representative or, in other words, $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ looks like $[0,1)$.

Comment: Then the difference $x−y$ isn't an integer multiple of 1?

Comment: @mark yes it is. An interger multiple of 1 is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

$x,y$ belong to distinct classes in $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ iff they have different fractional parts.